POST Video Stories using graph api facebook
hello guys im trying to automate a stories video post on facebook but dont know what im doing wrong, my picture stories function works fine but my video one is not working at all!!!
i tried to look over here and documentation for a answer but couldnt find a solution! in the first 10 calls i was getting errors from graph and from now on i keep getting erro 500!
does anyone knows what i can be doing wrong?
    function postStoriesVideoFacebook($fb, $pageId, $pageAccessToken, $mediaUrls) {
        $mediaUrls = 'https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4';
       // Etapa 1: Inicializar a sessão de upload
       $response = $fb->post("/{$pageId}/video_stories", [
        'upload_phase' => 'start',
    ], $pageAccessToken);

    $initData = $response->getDecodedBody();
    $videoId = $initData['video_id'];
    $uploadUrl = $initData['upload_url'];

    // Debugging - Verificando as variáveis
    var_dump($initData, $videoId, $uploadUrl);

    // Etapa 2: Fazer upload do vídeo usando a URL remota
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uploadUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        "Authorization: OAuth $pageAccessToken", // Passando o token como OAuth
        "file_url: $mediaUrls"
    ]);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $uploadResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $uploadData = json_decode($uploadResponse, true);

    // Debugging - Verificando a resposta do upload
    var_dump($uploadData);

    if (isset($uploadData['success']) && $uploadData['success'] === true) {
        // Etapa 3: Publicar o vídeo nos Stories
        $finishResponse = $fb->post("/{$pageId}/video_stories", [
            'upload_phase' => 'finish',
            'video_id' => $videoId,
        ], $pageAccessToken);

        $result = $finishResponse->getDecodedBody();

        // Debugging - Verificando a resposta da publicação
        var_dump($result);

        if (isset($result['success']) && $result['success'] === true) {
            return $result['post_id']; // Retorna o ID do post se a publicação for bem-sucedida
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Erro ao publicar o vídeo nos Stories.');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Erro ao fazer upload do vídeo.');
    }
}


forums , using direct the cURL options, postman etc

HTTP 500 -> Have a look into the logfiles.

Is this the actual media URL you used? If so - I am getting a 404 for that in my browser; do you have any reason to believe Facebook would get a different response?

the url was valid yesterday, now im using this one but keep getting 500 https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp4/sample-5s.mp4
